# Remove option new address from checkout billing and shipping information

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I'm trying to remove option add new address from checkout billing and shipping information from magento onepage checkout Also, would like to remove "change address" anchor from sidebar on checkout page. Any tips on how to accomplish?
My customers are only able to change address via email request, and require approval from administrators.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To remove option add new address from checkout billing and shipping information from magento onepage checkout,

copy `Abstract.php` file from `app\code\core\Mage\Checkout\Block\Onepage\Abstract.php to our local folder app\code\local\Mage\Checkout\Block\Onepage\Abstract.php`
and go to `getAddressesHtmlSelect($type)` method and comment below line:

```
$select->addOption('', Mage::helper('checkout')->__('New Address'));
```

To remove "change address" anchor from sidebar on checkout page, comment or remove below code

```
<span class="changelink"> <span class="separator">|</span> <a href="#billing" onclick="checkout.changeSection('opc-billing'); return false;"><?php echo $this->__('Change') ?></a></span>
```

from the below files:

> app/design/frontend/YOUR_THEME_NAME/YOUR_TEMPLATE_NAME/template/checkout/onepage/progress/billing.phtml
>
> app/design/frontend/YOUR_THEME_NAME/YOUR_TEMPLATE_NAME/template/checkout/onepage/progress/shipping.phtml

If you not able to find the file than you can copy them in your `YOUR_THEME_NAME/YOUR_TEMPLATE_NAME from the base/default`

Comment: It's working, thank you. My main problem was with "add new address". Didn't know i could just copy files from core to local to edit instead of extending to knew module. Once again, thank you a lot.

Comment: How could i use this method to disable new address to billing but allow new address into shipping?

Comment: @JonnyDevv, you have a `$type` parameter in `getAddressesHtmlSelect` method. You can wrap the `addOption` of new address into an if based on type being `shipping` or `billing`.